# javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Can't find application bundle in Webshpere

Tags: websphere-7

I have an application deployed on WEBSPHERE, which is up and running.

After that I have applied a patch for this application(patch will replaces `web.xml, jar's, class` etc.. files under deployment directory which is `<IBM_INST>/profiles/<APPDERVER>/installedApps` ) and I can see that application is started after patch apply.

But when I launch the `url` I'm getting below **error msg**:

```
Error 404: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Can't find application bundle. You can either define WOROOT, LOCALROOT and WOAINSTALLROOT as Java system properties (e.g. in your application server's launch script as command line arguments) or in the application Deployment Descriptor file (web.xml).
```

I have verified the `web.xml`. It looks fine.

NOTE:- If I redeploy using the `*.war` file from it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can't (or at least, not supposed) to "patch" WebSphere applications by directly modifying files under `installedApps`. You must do it in one of the following ways:

1. Interactively, through the WAS administration UI.
2. Through scripting, via the `AdminApp.update` command (or via the `AdminApplication` helper script, provided with WAS 7.0 onwards)